# Heat Transfer in A Cylinder of an Internal Combustion Engine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, heat-transfer

[image]

I am new in engineering, could anyone explain the approach to calculate the max heat generation, the heat transfer from the cylinder to the atmosphere and from cylinder to the piston.

I am also wondering about how does changing L3 affect the max heat generation which is allowed and why

the picture is the cross-section of the engine.

Comment: The max heat generated will be a function of the fuel type, the air / fuel ratio and the quality or completeness of combustion.  Are you looking for the heat transfer from the cylinder wall to the piston or the heat from the combustion process absorbed by the piston.  Why will L3 affect the max heat generated?

Comment: both heat transfer from the cylinder wall to the piston and the heat from the combustion process absorbed by the piston. I am also confused about how to calculate the rest of the temperatures if the only measurable one is T1